# Querying through data in mongoose database

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am currently trying to query through the data so that it only returns items with an id of bWYqm6-Oo(I only have 1 item as of now) between two specific dates 2019-09-19 and 2019-09-22. In this case it should only return the first 3 items in the database. I came up with a query but it only returns an empty array. Would somebody know how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

```
var findBy = {
    _id : bWYqm6-Oo,
    exercises : [
      {
        date: {
          $gte: 2019-09-19,
          $lt: 2019-09-22
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  UserModel.find(findBy).limit(5).exec((err, data) => {
      (err) ? res.json({"error" : "problem searching for exercises: " + err}) :  res.json(data);      
  });
```

My database looks like this:

```
{
    _id: "bWYqm6-Oo",
    user: "rommy",
    exersises: [
        {
        user_id: "bWYqm6-Oo",
        date: "2019-09-20T00:00:00.000Z",
        description: "stiup",
        duration: "22",
        _id: "pu90D-dHx"
        },
        {
        user_id: "bWYqm6-Oo",
        date: "2019-09-21T00:00:00.000Z",
        description: "pushup",
        duration: "22",
        _id: "YtfsJLOXb"
        },
        {
        user_id: "bWYqm6-Oo",
        date: "2019-09-20T00:00:00.000Z",
        description: "stiup",
        duration: "22",
        _id: "pu90D-dHx"
        },
        {
        user_id: "bWYqm6-Oo",
        date: "2019-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
        description: "stiup",
        duration: "22",
        _id: "pu90D-dHx"
        }
    ],
    __v: 9
}
```

Here is where I call my files in the server.js file:

Comment: @GregHerbowicz unfortunately I still get an empty array when I remove the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

The field `_id` on a document is always unique in mongo, therefore in your query

```
var findBy = {
    _id : bWYqm6-Oo,
    exercises : [
      {
        date: {
          $gte: 2019-09-22,
          $lt: 2019-09-22
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This part is redundant

```
exercises : [
      {
        date: {
          $gte: 2019-09-22,
          $lt: 2019-09-22
        }
      }
    ]
```

because there will only be one document with the `_id` of `'bWYqm6-Oo'`

If you want to query using date range you can do something like this:

```
var query = {
  'exercises.date': {$gte: '2019-09-22', $lt: '2019-09-22'}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get this error:  MongoError: unknown operator: $and" . I am using mongoose 5.4.11 and express 5.0.0-alpha.2

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with the syntax so not sure. What does your query look like?

Comment: Hi Isaac, I get still get this error: Can't use $and with Date. I used Date in my schema.

Comment: Now it returns me data but the problem is that instead of returning the first 3 items in the database (dates :2019-09-19 - 2019-09-22) it also returns the 4th item  2019-09-24.

Comment: @Roger you mean `exercises` from that user? Thats because you are querying for `users`, its gonna return you back all `users` with an exercise between those dates. If thats the case, `exercises` should be its own collection. There's no point in storing `user_id` on the exercise if its not.

Comment: Oh ok. I got it now. I thought it was possible to store all the exercises under a specific  user since it would look cleaner that way. Thank you Isaac for clearing that up.

Comment: @Roger You are already searching for users with specific exercises. I think want you want is to find only certain exercises. If I were you I would just filter the exercises in code once you have your `user`. Another alternative is to make `exercises` its own collection, and search using `user_id` and date range like before. Or you could do an aggregate query and `$project` what you need.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your help Isaac! Much appreciated.